# A combinatorial proof of Wilson's Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof

I am looking for a combinatorial proof of Wilson's Theorem. Something along the lines of this kind of proof.

$\textbf{Combinatorial proof of Fermat's Little Theorem}$

First consider a $p$ -tuple and let us say there are $a$ distinct numbers where $a > 0$ . Now the total possible tuples are $a^p$. Now we say $2$ tuples are equivalent if one is obtained by a cyclic permutation of the other. Now there are $a$  equivalence classes consisting of $1$ element and all other equivalence classes contain $p$ elements(Here we use the fact that $p$ is a prime). Now this implies that $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mathrm{mod} p$

Comment: See [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54018/a-particular-combinatorial-proof-of-wilsons-theorem) and [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.rit.edu%2F~%2520pga%2Fprimes.pdf&ei=RqyXVNCJN8yzuQSuwIK4Dg&usg=AFQjCNFHizPTCZLKnY9Y_csOCDAZPlGPzw&bvm=bv.82001339,d.c2E).

Comment: @user170039 thanks a lot but how do we get these kind of ideas for example adding one to all elements and then seeing the fixed point etc as in [this](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~%20pga/primes.pdf)

Comment: That's a difficult question but I think that experience helps.

Comment: I think I saw a combinatorial proof in a book prime numbers and telecommunications, I think it was a Springer book...

Comment: @RobertSoupe can you provide a link to the book I could not find it

Comment: @happymath The problem is I can't remember either. Maybe it was *Codes: An Introduction to Information Communication and Cryptography* by Norman Biggs? I'm not sure. Sorry if this is a red herring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a proof in Andrews book in number theory that goes as follows:

Consider a circunference with $p$ points that correspond to the vertices of a regular $p$-gon. How many polygons can have those vertices? $\frac{(p-1)!}{2}$. There are two types of polygons, those which are invariant under rotations of $\frac{2\pi}{p}$ radians, and those which give $p$ different polygons when rotated $p$ times.

How many are there of the first type? they are those which follow the rule that vertex with number $n$ is connected to vertex numbered $n+k$. There are $\frac{p-1}{2}$ of these.

We conclude $\frac{(p-1)!}{2}-\frac{p-1}{2}$ is a multiple of $p$. thus $(p-1)!-(p-1)$ is a multiple of $p$. so $2(p-1)!+1$ is a multiple of $2$, so $(p-1)!\equiv-1\bmod p$.

Comment: Fernandez thanks a lot for this proof though it seems a lot like the proof given [here](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~%20pga/primes.pdf) but still a nice perspective.